# java.util.ConcurrentModification handling in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read and write from one list in same block as shown in below code. doerDao.getParentNode method will give me one integer number and which i am again storing to same
list. i know it gives me Concurrent Modification error but is there any way where i can lock the object use the same list object to store the value and read from the list at the same time? or else i have to write a new method to get all the data in list and then use it.

```
int moduleId = 10;
List<Integer> getParentNode = new ArrayList<Integer>();

try 
{
    synchronized (getParentNode) 
    {           
        getParentNode.add(moduleId);
        for(int node : getParentNode)
        {
            int nodeId = doerDao.getParentNode( sessionFactory,  node);     
            getParentNode.add(nodeId);
        }             
    }          
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("Error is: "+e);
}
```

Comment: As the docs say, you get that exception if you modify the list while iterating through it. Which is exactly what you're doing.

Comment: yes i know but is there any mechanism available there (kind of a lock on read or write) which i can implement.

Comment: How do you suppose you could "lock" something and still modify it? No.

Comment: @BrianRoach We can implement it and even without getting the ConcurrentModificationException . for ref see the answer i have excepted. i am asking for this kind of mechanism .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `ConcurrentModificationException` has *in this case* nothing to do with threads and synchronization! In your case, an Iterator for the list is used *after* the list was modified.

In your case, I would suggest using a simple counting for-loop instead of a for-each loop, this will get rid of the Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at `CopyOnWriteArrayList<E>`, its a concurrent implementation for `ArrayList`.

Read more about [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: I tried that one it it worked but only for a first iteration then it handle the exception but not going further.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue sometimes back when I came to one solution.
I copied the objects I want to alter in the next list and after that I made changes in the original list.
You can also use [SynchronizedList](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SynchronizedList.html).